# How can I convert 6-hourly ERA-5 dataset to daily dataset in NetCDF file with R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I have a 6-hourly snow depth dataset from 1980-2022 in the form of NetCDF. Is there anyone who has a suggestion or example code for converting 6-hourly to the daily dataset NetCDF file with R? I searched many times for this issue but there is no example (except for NCO, NCL, python, or MATLAB). But I wanna make this in a NetCDF file by R.

Comment: Do you want to do this at global level or on a smaller region? Because, in the first case I would try to use `tapply` on the 3D data, in the second case - if the data is not that big - I would even consider another approach (e.g. tidync).

Comment: I wanna do for  0-60N lat, 30-60E longitude.